# Multiple database connections with Yii 2.0

Tags: yii2, multiple-databases

I have a system based a pure PHP and now I try to convert the codes into Yii2.
but I have a problem in this steps, I have a database for each user its mean when user register in my system, I will create a new db for it, and also there is a main database for system.
for example my databases list:

- mainDb
- customer1
- customer2
- customer3
- customer4
- customer5

So I don't know how many database should be there, in my current code, I define two function for example:
runSqlOnMainDB
runSqlOnCustomerDB
and in each of above function I set the connection string but how can I handle this problem with Yii2?

Thanks in advance for your help.

I would like to find a solution that help me to handle connection string based the name of the database.

Comment: You want to create a database for every customer that registers? Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Due to the volume of data and the demands of users, the information of each user, who is actually a company, must be stored in a new database from which I can output and provide it to them at any time.
Yes I do for any user or company and now I want to know how I can manage this
In its simplest form, I have more than 100 databases, which may increase every day. Can I have a solution for using yii2 framework?

Comment: The solution required here is normalization of the database. Can you please highlight the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

By default Yii 2 supports multiple databases that can be added in the respective db config files. But this won't apply for your use case as you will be generating databases dynamically.

You can use a particular set pattern to naming your databases for each customer. Like: db_customer_1, db_customer_2,...., db_customer_100, etc.

Here, the prefix 'db_customer_' will be fixed and after this append the customer ID.

In Yii 2, you can do following:

```
Yii::$app->get('db_customer_' . CUSTOMER_ID);
```

CUSTOMER_ID can be made available in session.

No extra table required. Simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate table to do this.

Assuming,you have a main database connection string in some other file like mainDb.php.

For ex-

1. Let's create a new table as customer_databases in mainDb database.Take columns like hostname,dbname,dbusername,dbpassword,customer_id.
2. Taken a reference of customer id as customer_id in customer_databases table
3. On login, get the details of customer from mainDb and accordingly make the connection as per customer id.
4. That's all, you have to do to make connection as per customer id

**Note-** For,not to make connection again and again, you can set the connection in session variable, and then return the connection string from db.php file.

For ref-

```
<?php
```

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["user_database"])) {

```
$connection = $_SESSION["user_database"];

$connection = json_decode($connection, true);

$hostname = ($connection['hostname']) ? $connection['hostname'] : "localhost";

$dbname = ($connection['dbname']) ? $connection['dbname'] : "dbname";

$username = ($connection['username']) ? $connection['username'] : "username";

$password = ($connection['password']) ? $connection['password'] : "password";

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $dbname,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
];
```

}else{

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
];
```

}

Also, don't forget to destroy the connection on logout.

Happy coding
Thanks,
Mukul Kashyap